# Blender 2.8 Cycles Sun Lamp bug?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

so I am currently working on a scene in blender that uses also volumetric scattering on a cube, so that I can create god rays with the help of the sun lamp.

An hour ago I wanted to look how that would look and Eevee and baked the lighting and renderd. However since then going back to cycles, I was not able to get my sun lamp working, it is there but it looks like for blender it is not there.

After trying many things out I just found out that as soon as I delete the volumetric cube my sun works fine again. So I tried making new cubes and new materials but what ever I try, my sun will not work at position where the cube is.

I think I somehow destroyed my blendfile. Right?

Scene shot from a few hours ago

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnnxJ.jpg
https://i.redd.it/ohbduzbdcpf31.jpg

will post viewport in a few minutes.

Comment: no volumetric https://imgur.com/1ZzNbDb

Comment: volumetric cube https://imgur.com/72DJsfI

Comment: Could you make it a little more clear which images are EEVEE adn which aren't? What are the material settings you're using, the lamp settings? And are you deleting the lighting bakes when you're done with them? EEVEE will continue to use the baked lighting even if the light probes are removed. You have to delete the lighting cache, too.

Comment: Hi, neither of the pictures i showed you are in eevee. Everything is in cycles.
My sun lamp in cycles does not work as before anymore. 
I am using the exact same settings as before which are the standard settings when you add a sun lamp just the strength is set to 50.
Bake in eevee is deleted. The cube has a volume scatter material, in the first pic it is just hidden and in the second its not hidden and you see the areas coverd by the cube are dark and the sun lamp does not work anymore. Materials are also unchanged, usual pbr setup.

Comment: OK. Try doing a new scene, re-linking the collections, and manually copying over the render/scene settings. If you do a linked copy, Blender will link all of the data, including the data that's causing the issue. Be sure to save the file before and after so you can submit a bug report, if indeed this is the solution.

Note: you could also create a new .blend file and append the collections in.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, will try that!